# C# Google Login API

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, firefox, google-signin

I'm currently developing a web site and Google Login is one of the features. So far so good. Google has a lot of documentation of its own API and some examples. BUT, here is my trouble.

I'm using C# and I followed this guide: [Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp)

And they already provide me a Visual Studio Solution ready to work and all.

Short Version: In Firefox 19.0.2 + firebug I get an error after I press the button and allow the app, like this

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'valueOf'
>
> $('#authResult').append(' ' + field + ': ' + authResult[field] + '
> ');

Rest of the function:

```
onSignInCallback: function(authResult) 
{
$('#authResult').html('Auth Result:<br/>');
for (var field in authResult) {
$('#authResult').append(' ' + field + ': ' + authResult[field] + '<br/>');
}
if (authResult['access_token']) {
// The user is signed in etc....
```

Running in Chrome everything works perfect and running on IE10 it also has bugs.

Hope you can help me please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a great first question.

Comment: are you not using the Google OWIN middleware which is the best way to connect your app to social logins like Google